# Admob view does not present a full screen ad on click

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, admob

I'm trying to figure out why its happening to my banner view, it should present a full screen ad on click, it does not do that.

my banner view is a subview of a viewcontroller witch is a part of a tabbar view controllers

what should I do, does anyone know whats my banner problem?
on click I get an ad in the bannerview and not a fullscreen down to top animated banner

HELP ME PLEASE !!!!

//Additional info

I found out that after my second ad request it does not open a full screen on touchup inside

I found the error, because I reload the banner by requesting another ad without initializing the bannerview

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you touch ad banner depends upon admob. You only must be sure that ad banner is touchable. Not always get a full screen on click, also can redirect tu app store, for example.

Comment: yeah i know, but i thing its a problem of my ad request or rootviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

So seeing some code on your implementation would help us diagnose this issue. Without seeing this code though, I'm assuming that if your banner is displaying properly and the full screen modal won't show it's a `rootviewController` issue.

Are you setting the `rootViewController` to be your `tabBarController`?

Comment: no I set the root viewcontroller as the selected view controller, otherwise I dont see ad

Comment: You can check out an example at http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/AdCatalog/Classes/AdvancedLayoutUseCases/TabbedViewExample/TabbedViewExampleController.m?repo=adcatalog-ios. If you implement it like this, you can end up with AdMob singleton across your views. I would say try setting your rootViewController to something higher in your view hierarchy.

Comment: I tried all the hierarchy levels, the only one showed an ad is the current one (the lowest).

Comment: Can you show us some code that outlines how you're creating your ad and adding it into your view hierarchy, and some code that shows your view hierarchy is set up?